# Large Dataset Cron Job Suggestions

Tags: php, cron, background-process

I have an interesting situation of calculations that need to be made in a project, and am looking for an efficient way to handle it. Here is the scenario.

We are making a "Polling" website, where users answer Poll questions. They can answer each question once.

We are generating a "Score" for every user based on their answers. They receive 1 point for each other user that answered the same.

For Example:

```
Question 1 has 2 answers, "Yes" and "No"

 7 Users answered "Yes" and 3 answered "No"

  Each User that answered "Yes" adds 7 points to their score
  Each User that answered "No" adds 3 points to their score

   If a 4th User answers "No", 1 extra point is added to each User that answered "No"
```

As you can imagine, it would be far too many calculations to do this on the fly, since lots of user scores must be regenerated every time a question is answered. So I want to do this as a Cron Job every X hours.

My Data currently returns a single Row for each Question answered by a single user, along with how many points each answer is worth (comma separated: 7,3)

How should I go about regenerating these results? I do not want to use a simple "Foreach" to loop through every User, as this doesn't seem like it will scale as the User base grows. Is there a way to run PHP scripts in the background or concurrently, as to not cause the loop to hang?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have explained the database a bit too.

This is a WordPress website, so some of the data is in the default WordPress postmeta table. The tally is stored as comma separated meta_key value for the "Post" (Poll question)

All answers are store in their own answers table. Each answer is a row in the table, and it includes user_id, post_id (of poll question), answer chosen(index of comma separated meta_key value)

And this is the query I am using to get all the answers for a particular User:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_myo_ip` LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON `wp_myo_ip`.`myo_polling_id` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` AND `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'myo-votes'  WHERE `wp_myo_ip`.`myo_polling_ip` = 1
```

The `myo_polling_ip` column is actually the User ID

Comment: I'm not sure if I get this correctly, but couldn't this scenario force a recursive algorithm that has no stop mechanism?

Comment: You don't have to foreach through every user if you save your answers in a database, just `UPDATE scores SET score = (score + 1) WHERE question_id = 1 AND answer='No'`, something like that would update the score for all users that answered no on question #1.

Comment: use a trigger to update a centralised score tally for each question every time you insert an answer.  You can always use a timed-job to recalculate things to make sure it tallies properly afterwards, but the trigger-based version would give you a pretty accurate running total that auto-updates itself.

Comment: Oldskool, I like your methodology, I will just have to adjust it to work with my current Database setup. I should probably add an extra table that only tracks total score so I can check the answers table for an answer and increment only those User scores.

Answer (score 0):

Based on absolutly no database information given ...

```
UPDATE answer_tbl 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT answer_tbl.id, IF(answer_tbl.answer = 'YES', COUNT(yes_tbl.id), COUNT(no_tbl.id)) AS score
                FROM answer_tbl
                    LEFT JOIN answer_tbl AS yes_tbl ON answer_tbl.question_id = yes_tbl.question_id AND yes_tbl.answer = 'YES'
                    LEFT JOIN answer_tbl AS no_tbl ON answer_tbl.question_id = no_tbl.question_id AND no_tbl.answer = 'NO'
                WHERE 1
                GROUP BY answer_tbl.id) AS score_tbl
    SET answer_tbl.score AS score_tbl.score
    WHERE answer_tbl.id = score_tbl.score
```

Comment: I have added some clarification of the database. The site is running off WordPress with extra custom tables